# How to get standard library c++ using clang for cross compiling

Tags: clang++, llvm-clang

First of all: I have read all similar posts and have been looking for over a Week. The Question is not repeated and I searched a lot.

Basically i m trying to compile a simple helloWorld c++ program with docker using clang as cross compiler for raspberry pi 3.

I am using VM Ubuntu 18.04

compiler clang 8
when i cross compile the code in docker using clang:

fatal error: 'bits/c++config.h' no such file or directory ...

here is CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.2)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(triple arm-linux-gnueabihf)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET ${triple})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET ${triple})
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")

set(DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING=True)
set(DLLVM_DEFAULT_TARGET_TRIPLE=arm-linux-gnueabihf)
set(DLLVM_TARGET_ARCH=ARM)
set(DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=ARM)

#executing...
project (arm_cross)
add_executable(hello hello.cpp )
```

i expected after invoke make to get executable file for arm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution as follow what i did
Firstly backup /usr/include then move /usr/arm/include file to up. Finally run your 32 bit arm application. 
This step can be automated by simple shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I have never dealt with docker. But half a year ago, I also had an issue of cross compiling code for raspberry, under mac os though. Anyways, I used clang as a toolchain, and finally I have succeed.

Key point is to provide clang with good target rootfs. I just mounted real raspberry through sshfs.

Another thing is that I didn't put compiler settings into CMakeLists.txt but provided cmake with toolchain file.

My cmake toolchain file:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

# Custom toolchain-specific definitions for your project
set(PLATFORM_ARM "1")
set(PLATFORM_COMPILE_DEFS "COMPILE_GLES")

# There we go!
# Below, we specify toolchain itself!

SET(TARGET_TRIPLE arm-linux-gnueabihf)

# Specify your target rootfs mount point on your compiler host machine
SET(TARGET_ROOTFS /Volumes/rootfs-${TARGET_TRIPLE})

# Specify clang paths
SET(LLVM_DIR /Users/stepan/projects/shared/toolchains/llvm-7.0.darwin-release-x86_64/install)
SET(CLANG ${LLVM_DIR}/bin/clang)
SET(CLANGXX ${LLVM_DIR}/bin/clang++)

# Specify compiler (which is clang)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   ${CLANG})
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CLANGXX})

# Specify binutils

SET (CMAKE_AR      "${LLVM_DIR}/bin/llvm-ar" CACHE FILEPATH "Archiver")
SET (CMAKE_LINKER  "${LLVM_DIR}/bin/llvm-ld" CACHE FILEPATH "Linker")
SET (CMAKE_NM      "${LLVM_DIR}/bin/llvm-nm" CACHE FILEPATH "NM")
SET (CMAKE_OBJDUMP "${LLVM_DIR}/bin/llvm-objdump" CACHE FILEPATH "Objdump")
SET (CMAKE_RANLIB  "${LLVM_DIR}/bin/llvm-ranlib" CACHE FILEPATH "ranlib")

# You may use legacy binutils though.
#SET(BINUTILS /usr/local/Cellar/arm-linux-gnueabihf-binutils/2.31.1)
#SET (CMAKE_AR      "${BINUTILS}/bin/${TARGET_TRIPLE}-ar" CACHE FILEPATH "Archiver")
#SET (CMAKE_LINKER  "${BINUTILS}/bin/${TARGET_TRIPLE}-ld" CACHE FILEPATH "Linker")
#SET (CMAKE_NM      "${BINUTILS}/bin/${TARGET_TRIPLE}-nm" CACHE FILEPATH "NM")
#SET (CMAKE_OBJDUMP "${BINUTILS}/bin/${TARGET_TRIPLE}-objdump" CACHE FILEPATH "Objdump")
#SET (CMAKE_RANLIB  "${BINUTILS}/bin/${TARGET_TRIPLE}-ranlib" CACHE FILEPATH "ranlib")

# Specify sysroot (almost same as rootfs)
SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${TARGET_ROOTFS})
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${TARGET_ROOTFS})

# Specify lookup methods for cmake
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

# Sometimes you also need this:
# set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

# Specify raspberry triple
set(CROSS_FLAGS "--target=${TARGET_TRIPLE}")

# Specify other raspberry related flags
set(RASP_FLAGS "-D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS")

# Gather and distribute flags specified at prev steps.
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${CROSS_FLAGS} ${RASP_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${CROSS_FLAGS} ${RASP_FLAGS}")

# Use clang linker. Why?
# Well, you may install custom arm-linux-gnueabihf binutils,
# but then, you also need to recompile clang, with customized triple;
# otherwise clang will try to use host 'ld' for linking,
# so... use clang linker.
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fuse-ld=lld)
```

My article with detailed description is [here](https://dyatkovskiy.com/2018/11/04/173/).

Hopefully it will help.
I also would separate this problem on two steps:
1. Get it compiled by clang.
2. Integrate compilation settings into docker.

Good luck!

Comment: hey @StepanDyatkovskiy saw your blog since long. I found a solution which is not proper, so under /usr/   i installed g++-7-arm-linux-gbueabihf  then i got a directory like /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf. if i remove include from /usr/include and move include from arm-linux-gnueabihf to up (one folder up ) then it is work. ;( What cause this behave ?

Comment: Usually it happens due to hardcoded include directories into compilers. Or it hardcodes way how to find some directories. I suspect, in your case gcc expects to see includes in /include/<target-triple>/, where "triple" is arm-linux-gnueabihf.

If you can modify compilation flags for app you want to compile, just add include search path "-I<path>" to CXXFLAGS.

If not, then best thing is to follow legacy app build instructions, use toolchain they propose to use and so on.

Comment: @ Stepan Dyatkovskiy i guesso too that compiler include path is hardcoded. I could ignore default path with compiler arguments but either can be ignore or only default include path. Therefore i used toolchain and making a symbolic link. Thank you!

Comment: @mWelt, you're welcome. Also it is usefull to dry run compiler with -### option. It will show you all commands gcc/clang driver going to call during compilation. E.g. "g++ -### test.cpp"